# How to select everything before the first uppercase symbol that follows a lowercase symbol

Tags: regex, stringr

In an example:

`Hello my name is Karl, I am finHello my name is Karl, I am fine`

I want to remove everything before the second Hello. So to:

`Hello my name is Karl, I am fine`.

It would be nice if you explain all the functions within the regex, too.

I realized that this needs to be done with str_remove().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.*(?=[a-z][A-Z]).
```

- `.*` Match everything till the lookahead assertion condition
- `(?=` Lookahead assertion - assert that the following regex matches

  - `[a-z][A-Z]` Match consecutive lowercase and uppercase letters
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.` Match one more character after lookahead as the last lowercase is under it

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIJk0Z/1)

##### R Example

```
library(stringr)

s <- "Hello my name is Karl, I am fineHello my name is Karl, I am fine"
print(str_match(s, ".*(?=[a-z][A-Z]).")[1])  # Hello my name is Karl, I am fine
```

Comment: But this is not vectorialized, it's not a str_remove(). It's important that it has to be a str_remove(), because it would give a NA if there are no uppercases following a lowercase.

Comment: @GiulioGCantone, please check my edit.